# How do I create a queryset to display products that are linked to a category, that is shown by each category slug?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a product model and a productcategory model. The products are linked to the productcategory by a category attribute. I want to create a query that displays ONLY products that are in a category, when the webpage is displayed for that specific category.

The way I have my views currently setup, I get an attribute error, saying the view has no attribute of slug.

Models:

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True,
                related_name='children', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Product(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category    = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, related_name='ProductsCategory', null=True, blank=True,
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug        = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    price       = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', null=True, blank=True)
```

Views:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    look_up = 'slug'
    template_name = 'products/products.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        category = ProductCategory.objects.get(self.slug)
        products = Product.filter(category=category)
        return products
```

Urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', CategoryView.as_view(), name='shop'),
    path('<slug:product_category>/', ProductListView.as_view(), name='products'),
    path('<slug:product_category>/<slug:product>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that it should be `Product.objects.filter`, what is wrong with this code? What is your question?

Comment: I have tried Product.objects.filter and that doesn’t work either. When I add in this code and now try to go to one of the pages of a category, Django gives me an attribute error, saying slug is not an attribute of ProductListView.

Comment: What do you expect the value of `self.slug` to be?  `self` in this case is **not** the model instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following, would be able to help more seeing your urls but this should get you closer.

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'products/products.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        category = ProductCategory.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs.get('product_category'))
        products = category.ProductsCategory.all()
        return products
```

Comment: will try this... just added my urls if this could help more. thank you

Comment: @leonking93 I've updated the answer, let me know if this helps.

Comment: this worked!! Thanks so much. Im in school and am actively trying to learn python and the django framework.

Comment: @leonking93 glad I could be of help :)